# newbie: append serialized integers into database column and retrieve them back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, serialization, activerecord, deserialization

How Could I store integers (user id's ranging from 1 to 9999) serialized in a database column and retrieve them back?

In my User model I have invites column,

```
User model
serialize: invites
invites = text field
```

Now I'm trying to do 2 things:

- Append the user_id integer (from 1 to 9999) serialized in a column "invites"
- Retrieve all the user id's back from the User.invited column ( deserialize it ? )

Comment: Dont do that_ Never ever store more than one datum into one filed, if you want to access them seperately

Comment: Anyone suggestion on how to do this, or in another way or is this totally not doable? thought serialization could be used for integers also

Comment: Create an invites table, with inviter id and invitee id, every invitation is a row, linked to the two actors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize):

> **serialize(attr_name, class_name = Object)**
>
> If you have an attribute that needs to be saved to the database as an object, and retrieved as the same object, then specify the name of that attribute using this method and it will be handled automatically. The serialization is done through YAML. If `class_name` is specified, the serialized object must be of that class on retrieval or `SerializationTypeMismatch` will be raised.

So, if you want to store an array of integers as a serialized object, then:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    serialize :invites, Array
    #...
end
```

You'd want the `invites` column to be a `text` column in the database (not `string`!) to avoid running into size issues.

Then you can treat `user.invites` as a plain Array:

```
user.invites = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
user.invites.push(11)
```

That of course doesn't verify that that numbers are valid or that you don't have duplicates (but you could use a [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) instead of an Array for that), it also won't prevent you from putting a string in there.

I don't recommend that you do this though, serialization is almost always a mistake that will come back to bite you later. A serialized column is an opaque blob of data as far as the database is concerned: you can't update it in-place, you can't query it, all you can do is pull it out of the database and put it back. `serialize` uses YAML for serialization and that's an awful format if you need to work with your serialized data inside the database; you can also run into [interesting encoding issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8570173/479863) during upgrades.

You're better off setting up a traditional association table and a separate model (possibly using [`has_many ... :through =>`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association)) to handle this situation.

Comment: Okay I see now I was on the total wrong road for this, Now I understand I should better use a has_many through it will also be easier to display the data in the views, thx for making this clear