# Storing an Array in rails 4 using sqlite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I'm looking to add a row to my "posts" database that can store an array that holds multiple user id's. I noticed that none of the other questions asked on here were using rails 4. I think that this is going to require me to serialize the information but I'm not sure how to do this.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try using [`to_json`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json) to serialize the array?

Answer (score 5):

Create a migration

`rails g migration AddSomethingToPosts something:text`

In your model add

`serialize :something, Array`

here is more info: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize

also you can use store -> http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html, and it probably will be a better choice :)

Comment: What makes store be the better choice. thanks for the input and links

Comment: How would I go about appending to the end of the array?

Comment: Store is a wrapper around serialize, giving you easy way to create accossors in case you want something more than a simple array. To append use `@post.something << value`, in your controller.

Comment: Do I have to use store to use that append method?

Comment: don't think so, serialize should do fine :), here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485807/newbie-append-serialized-integers-into-database-column-and-retrieve-them-back

Comment: @BelowAverageProgrammer Don't forget that you cannot make any type of query you want for Store!