# How to store a simple string array in SQLite 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, database, rails-activerecord

I want to do some testing...

If there is an array, `array = [a, b, c, d]`, I want to save it in my database ([SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) 3) and call the elements when a user types 'array' in the input area.

I'm using cloud9 for testing! In 'migrates' folder, there is a file that has this code.

```
class CreateFans < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :fans do |t|
      t.string :content


      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I know I have to use this page for defining variable names of database data. but where should I put on my 'array' data?

*The conclusion is...*

I want to know how to save and recall an array in my database!

Comment: possible duplicate of [newbie: append serialized integers into database column and retrieve them back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485807/newbie-append-serialized-integers-into-database-column-and-retrieve-them-back)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the array into a string to store it in the database. When you pull it from the database, convert it back into an array.

```
myModel.myDbObject = array.join("")
```

Then when pulling from the database...

```
array[] = myModel.myDbObject.split("")
```

That's essentially what I had to do for one of my Ruby on Rails applications.

Or for array elements longer than just one letter

```
myModel.myDbObject = array.join(",")
```

Pulling from database

```
array[] = myModel.myDbObject = array.split(",")
```