# Encoding utf-8 string with MySQL and Rails 3 not working

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding, utf-8

yet another encoding problem with MySQL, UTF-8 and Rails 3 application.

We recently migrated our code from Rails 2 to Rails 3. We use MySQL and the `mysql2` gem. The thing is, in our old database we had content that included some utf-8 chars instead of their corresponding htmlentities, such as `\xC3\x9F` for an o with a dieresis.

We have those strings as a YAML serialization of some strings that have to go into the website. The problem is that when the records from the database are loaded into the ActiveRecord objects, this is done with strange characters, thus showing really nasty on the web. For example, `ß` is shown as `Ã` and so on.

I played a bit with the new encoding magic of Rails 3, trying various combinations of `force_encoding` and `encode` methods with no luck.

For the record, mysql is started with this two lines:

```
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Any idea on what are we doing wrong, why the YAML is not reading correctly those escaped characters and what could we do to solve the issue?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just found out what the problem was: the yaml text was done with `syck` and now `psyck` is not liking it much.

I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8570162/196708